# importing a css file inside a Nuxt layout retuens [object Object]

Tags: vue.js, webpack, css-loader, nuxt.js

in Nuxt project I want to add an external stylesheet to a layout

layouts/default.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img src="~assets/img/test.jpg" />
       <!--resolvs to: <img src="/_nuxt/assets/img/cv.jpg"> -->
    <nuxt/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~assets/style.css" />
       <!-- resolved to: <link rel="stylesheet" href="[object Object]" />
  </div>
</template>
```

I use this option in nuxt.config.js (webpack extend)

```
vueLoader.options.transformAssetUrls = {
        img: ['src', 'data-src'],
        link: 'href', 
    }
```

when I remove link from transformAssetUrls, it keep it untouched, but the stylesheet dosen't load

Comment: Please, elaborate, what result are you trying to achieve this way, as instead of using pages's [head](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head#the-head-method) property, for example?

Comment: The `assets` directory is intended to contain your un-compiled assets such as LESS, SASS, or JavaScript. So move your CSS file in the `static` folder and load it `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />`

Comment: But the simple way is to used `head` meta to load external CSS from your layout script: `export default {
  head: {
    link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'style.css' }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: even i putted the css file inside 'assests' by mistake, shouldn't it be copied with the same name to the distination folder and accessed by '~assets/style.css'? @NicolasPennec